# Android validation empty form

Tags: java, android, forms, validation, android-studio

I don’t have any idea , why this code does not working ??

```
 reg.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            final String e = Email.getText()
                    .toString();
            Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            final String p = Password.getText()
                    .toString();

            // check the empty fields
            if (Email.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || Password.getText().toString()
                    .equals("")) {
                alert.showAlertDialog(Register.this, "wrong",
                        "please fill the form ", false);
                return;
            }

        }


    });

}
```

please any one can help me ? 
which wrong in this code , this code for android application on android studio

Comment: Can you tell where the error is coming ..or show the Logcat.

Comment: Is your problem that `e` and `p` are always empty strings?

Answer (score 2):

`isEmpty(str)`: Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "String is empty or null!");
}
```

Use [TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) for checking empty text fields.

Try this:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e) || TextUtils.isEmpty(p) {
  alert.showAlertDialog(Register.this, "wrong",
                        "please fill the form ", false);
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add check for `Email.getText().toString().length() == 0` in your validation logic, see if it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could you use `.length()` to check if the fields are note empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 final String e = Email.getText().toString();
 if (e.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//done is button 
name=findViewById(R.id.txt_name); 
final String Name = name.getText().toString();  
done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {
                    name.setError("Field is req");
                    return;
                }
}
```